# React making onClick event specific for each element

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-hooks, frontend

I want to add a border when the class is "transporation active" but when I click one of the icons, all of them become active. I want only the clicked one to become active. This is for selecting categories. My react code is like this:

```js
    const [transportationClick, setTransportationClick] = useState(false);
      const handleTransportationClick = () => setTransportationClick(!transportationClick);
    
/* where I use it */

    <div className="transportation-types">
                  <div className={transportationClick ? "transportation active" : "transportation"} onClick={handleTransportationClick}>
                    <div className="transportation-icon">
                      <FaCar />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div className={transportationClick ? "transportation active" : "transportation"} onClick={handleTransportationClick}>
                    <div className="transportation-icon">
                      <FaBus />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div className={transportationClick ? "transportation active" : "transportation"} onClick={handleTransportationClick}>
                    <div className="transportation-icon">
                      <FaWalking />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that all the icons share the same state, which results in all of the icons becoming active when one of them is clicked. There are several ways to solve this - you can refactor each icon into it's own component:

```
const Icon = ({ icon }) => {
  const [transportationClick, setTransportationClick] = useState(false);
  const handleTransportationClick = () => setTransportationClick(!transportationClick);

  return (
    <div className={transportationClick ? "transportation active" : "transportation"} onClick={handleTransportationClick}>
       <div className="transportation-icon">
         {icon}
       </div>
    </div>
  )
}

const Parent = () => {
  return (
    <div className="transportation-types">
      <Icon icon={<FaCar />} />
      <Icon icon={<FaBus />} />
      <Icon icon={<FaWalking />} />    
   </div>
  )
}
```

Or set the state to an index corresponding to the order your showing the icon in:

```
const Parent = () => {
  const [transportationClick, setTransportationClick] = useState(0)

  return (
    <div className="transportation-types">
      <div
        className={transportationClick === 0 ? 'transportation active' : 'transportation'}
        onClick={() => setTransportationClick(0)}
      >
        <div className="transportation-icon">
          <FaCar />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div
        className={transportationClick === 1 ? 'transportation active' : 'transportation'}
        onClick={() => setTransportationClick(1)}
      >
        <div className="transportation-icon">
          <FaBus />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div
        className={transportationClick === 2 ? 'transportation active' : 'transportation'}
        onClick={() => setTransportationClick(2)}
      >
        <div className="transportation-icon">
          <FaWalking />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: but in this way, it isn't possible to choose multiple icons

Comment: In the first implementation, it should be possible. If you want to access the icons that are active in the parent component for form submission etc., you could pass a handler to set some state in the parent component.